# How can I make text and image be on the same height alignment?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I am trying to make the text and image be on the same level but when I add the text the image moves, I am unsure on how to fix it and looking for help.

I thought of trying flexbox but I don't think that will work?

[CurrentLooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmU1b.png)

Relevant Code:

HTML:

```html
 <div class="ProjectBox">

   <div>
     <h1>test</h1>
   </div>
   
   <div>
   <img src="Commands.png" alt="Bot commands" style="width: 270px " class="IMG2"/> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

````css
.OuterPage {
  margin: 70px;
}

.ProjectBox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fa3f32;
  border: #fa3f32;
}

.Flex1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 50px;
}

.IMG2 {
  position:relative; 
  left: 300px;
  top: 40px;
}```
````

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "same level". If you mean aligned at the same height, you have multiple solutions. You can create a [grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or a [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), or you can use [absolute](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) positioning to prevent elements from affecting each other with their own dimensions/positions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap try using row and inline-block to align them together

```
<div class="ProjectBox row">
       <div class="d-inline-block">
         <h1>test</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="d-inline-block">
       <img src="Commands.png" alt="Bot commands" style="width: 270px " /> 
       </div>
     </div>
```

If it is pure css, can do it with

```
<div style="display:inline-block "class="ProjectBox ">
   <div style="display:inline-block">
     <h1>test</h1>
   </div>
   <div style="display:inline-block">
   <img src="Commands.png" alt="Bot commands" style="width: 270px " /> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `position: relative;` to your .ProjectBox class
and `position:absolute;` + `top: 0;` to your .IMG2 class

Comment: to broad as an answer. Also it will cause a collision of the elements as the image will be moved out of flow